# R Insert Value within Dataframe

Tags: r, copy, comparison, tidyverse, rows

I have a very complex problem, i hope someone can help -> i want to copy a row value (i.e. Player 1 or Player 2) into two other rows (for Player 3 and 4) if and only if these players are in the same Treatment, Group and Period AND this player was indeed picked (see column Player.Picked)

I know that with tidyverse I can group_by my columns of interest: Treatment, Group, and Period.
However, I am unsure how to proceed with the condition that Player Picked is fulfilled and then how to extract this value appropriately for the players 3 and 4 in the same treatment, group, period.

The column "extracted.Player 1/2 Value" should be the output. (I have manually provided the first four correct solutions).

Any ideas? Help would be very much appreciated. Thanks a lot in advance!

```
df
T   Player    Group      Player.Picked   Period     Player1/2Value         extracted.Player1/2Value
1     1         6              1         1          10
1     2         6              1         1          9 
1     3         5              2         1          NA                          -> 4
1     4         6              1         1          NA                          -> 10
1     5         3              1         1          NA                      
1     1         5              2         1          8                           
1     2         1              0         1          7
1     3         6              1         1          NA                          -> 10
1     4         2              2         1          NA
1     5         2              2         1          NA
1     1         1              0         1          7
1     2         2              2         1          11
1     3         3              1         1          NA
1     4         4              1         1          NA   
1     5         4              1         1          NA
1     1         2              2         1          21
1     2         4              1         1          17
1     3         1              0         1          NA
1     4         5              2         1          NA                           -> 4
1     5         6              1         1          NA  
1     1         3              1         1          12
1     2         3              1         1          15
1     3         4              1         1          NA
1     4         1              0         1          NA
1     5         1              0         1          NA
1     1         4              1         1          11 
1     2         5              2         1          4
1     3         2              2         1          NA
1     4         3              1         1          NA
1     5         5              2         1          NA
```

Comment: Can you add information about what do you mean by a player being picked? i.e. a player is picked when it has a Player.Picked value of 1 or 2 but not 0? In addition, what exact player values do you want to replace what NAs?

Comment: `i want to copy a row value (i.e. Player 1 or Player 2) into two other rows` - how do you decide whether to copy the value from player 1 or player 2?

Comment: hello! I will try to provide an example. In the first line, player 1 is in group 6. For all players 3,4 in group 6, player 1 would be picked. Only one player (out of two players (1,2) can ever be picked). If player.picked equals 0, neither player 1 nor player 2 have been picked.

Comment: You could imagine that player 1 and 2 both compete with each other. Player 5 picks one out of the two or none. Player 3 and 4 have then access to the "picked" player's (1 or 2) information or to none. If player 5 picks player 1, then Player.Picked = 1. If player 5 picks player 2, then Player.Picked = 2. If he picks none, then Player.Picked = 0.

Comment: For each `Treatment`, `Group` and `Period` only one player will be picked, right? So in the end do you want only one row for these combinations (`summarise`) or multiple rows?

Comment: Consider Group 5 / Player 5, Player 1 was picked. Player1/2Value for Player 1 is 8 but extracted.Player1/2Value is 4?

Comment: @Ronak Skah exactly, for each treatment, group and period only one player (or none) will be picked) -> i want the picked player to appear in the row of player 3 and 4 in the same treatment, group and period

Comment: @  ismirsehregal ->  extracted.Player1/2Value would be 8 (i don't want to divide the value by 2, i wrote Player1/2 because it can be either the value from player 1 or 2)

Comment: `extracted.Player1/2Value would be 8` exactly, but it's 4 in your dataset.

Comment: Yes because the picked player was player 2. (in other words player 2 is the picked player in group 5) -> player 3 and player 4 see player 2's value

Comment: I thought because of the consider that this was meant what would be if

Comment: in Group5 Player5 picked Player1 not Player2 (see last row).

Comment: i am very sorry this was a typo.

Comment: So extracted.Player1/2Value should be 8 not 4 (for Group 5), right?

Comment: i have now corrected the typo, player 5 picked player 2 -> so extracted value should be 4. sorry for the inconvenience

Comment: Just updated my answer with your latest dataset.

Comment: Thank you again, really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understood the required logic; here I'm assuming that Player 5 always picks Player 1 or 2 per Group.

So, here is my go at this using `library(data.table)`:

```
library(data.table)

DT <- data.table::data.table(
                 check.names = FALSE,
                           T = c(1L,1L,1L,
                                 1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,
                                 1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,
                                 1L,1L,1L,1L),
                      Player = c(1L,2L,3L,
                                 4L,5L,1L,2L,3L,4L,5L,1L,2L,3L,4L,5L,
                                 1L,2L,3L,4L,5L,1L,2L,3L,4L,5L,1L,
                                 2L,3L,4L,5L),
                       Group = c(6L,6L,5L,
                                 6L,3L,5L,1L,6L,2L,2L,1L,2L,3L,4L,4L,
                                 2L,4L,1L,5L,6L,3L,3L,4L,1L,1L,4L,
                                 5L,2L,3L,5L),
               Player.Picked = c(1L,1L,2L,
                                 1L,1L,2L,0L,1L,2L,2L,0L,2L,1L,1L,1L,
                                 2L,1L,0L,2L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,0L,0L,
                                 1L,2L,2L,2L),
                      Period = c(1L,1L,1L,
                                 1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,
                                 1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,1L,
                                 1L,1L,1L,1L),
            `Player1/2Value` = c(10L,9L,NA,
                                 NA,NA,8L,7L,NA,NA,NA,7L,11L,NA,NA,
                                 NA,21L,17L,NA,NA,NA,12L,15L,NA,NA,NA,
                                 11L,4L,NA,NA,NA),
  `extracted.Player1/2Value` = c(NA,NA,4L,
                                 10L,NA,NA,NA,10L,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,
                                 NA,NA,NA,NA,4L,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,
                                 NA,NA,NA,NA)
)

setorderv(DT, cols = c("T", "Group", "Period", "Player"))

Player5PickedDT <- DT[Player == 5, Player.Picked, by = c("T", "Group", "Period")]
setnames(Player5PickedDT, old = "Player.Picked", new = "Player5Picked")
DT <- DT[Player5PickedDT, on = c("T", "Group", "Period")]

extractedDT <- DT[Player == Player5Picked & Player5Picked > 0, `Player1/2Value`, by = c("T", "Group", "Period")]
setnames(extractedDT, old = "Player1/2Value", new = "extractedValue")
DT[, "Player5Picked" := NULL]

DT <- extractedDT[DT, on = c("T", "Group", "Period")]
DT[, extractedValue := fifelse(Player %in% c(3, 4), yes = extractedValue, no = NA_real_)]

setcolorder(DT, c("T", "Group", "Period", "Player", "Player.Picked", "Player1/2Value", "extracted.Player1/2Value", "extractedValue"))

DT
```

The resulting table differs from your expected result (`extracted.Player1/2Value` vs `extractedValue`, but in my eyes it is following the explained logic):

```
    T Group Period Player Player.Picked Player1/2Value extracted.Player1/2Value extractedValue
 1: 1     1      1      1             0              7                       NA             NA
 2: 1     1      1      2             0              7                       NA             NA
 3: 1     1      1      3             0             NA                       NA             NA
 4: 1     1      1      4             1             NA                       NA             NA
 5: 1     1      1      5             0             NA                       NA             NA
 6: 1     2      1      1             2             21                       NA             NA
 7: 1     2      1      2             2             11                       NA             NA
 8: 1     2      1      3             2             NA                       NA             11
 9: 1     2      1      4             2             NA                       NA             11
10: 1     2      1      5             2             NA                       NA             NA
11: 1     3      1      1             1             12                       NA             NA
12: 1     3      1      2             1             15                       NA             NA
13: 1     3      1      3             1             NA                       NA             12
14: 1     3      1      4             2             NA                       NA             12
15: 1     3      1      5             1             NA                       NA             NA
16: 1     4      1      1             0             11                       NA             NA
17: 1     4      1      2             1             17                       NA             NA
18: 1     4      1      3             1             NA                       NA             11
19: 1     4      1      4             1             NA                       NA             11
20: 1     4      1      5             1             NA                       NA             NA
21: 1     5      1      1             2              8                       NA             NA
22: 1     5      1      2             1              4                       NA             NA
23: 1     5      1      3             2             NA                        4              4
24: 1     5      1      4             2             NA                        4              4
25: 1     5      1      5             2             NA                       NA             NA
26: 1     6      1      1             1             10                       NA             NA
27: 1     6      1      2             1              9                       NA             NA
28: 1     6      1      3             1             NA                       10             10
29: 1     6      1      4             1             NA                       10             10
30: 1     6      1      5             1             NA                       NA             NA
    T Group Period Player Player.Picked Player1/2Value extracted.Player1/2Value extractedValue
```

Comment: Thank you so so much! This is the exactly what I was looking for. I am sorry for having difficulty to explain the logic! But the solution is correct!